# Проектирование связей сущностей БД

Tags: sql, база-данных

Метод - некий алгоритм измерения чего либо.
Показатель - то что измеряем.
Диапазон - в каком диапазоне измеряем.
Характеристика - характеристика, которая влияет на погрешность измерения.

И мы для данного метода, для выбранного показателя, для нужного диапазона, выставляем предел погрешности для необходимой характеристики.

Тут все друг без друга не может быть.
То есть если мы хотим добавить показатель, мы не сможем добавить его, не добавив к нему диапазон и не добавив погрешность для него.

Вопрос в том, правильно ли сделана схема. К примеру, если я хочу запросить для данного метода все его показатели, характеристики или диапазоны... Нужно будет делать каждый раз GROUP BY.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66635/discussion-on-question-by-lfds----).